# Amazon EC2 Spot Alert

Tags: amazon-ec2, alert

I use 1 spot instance and would like to be emailed when prices for my instance size and region are above a threshold.  I can then take appropriate action and shut down and move instance to another region if needed.  Any ideas on how to be alerted to the prices?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to go about this that I can think of:

**1) Since you only have one instance, you could set a CloudWatch alarm for your instance in a region that will notify you when the spot price rises above what you're willing to pay hourly.**

If you create an Alarm, and tell it to use the EstimatedCharges metric for the AmazonEC2 service, and choose a period of an hour, then you are basically telling CloudWatch to send you an email whenever the hourly spot price for your instance in the region it's running in is above your threshold for wanting to pay.

Once you get the email, you can then shut the instance down and start one up in another region, and leave it running with its own alarm.

---

**2) You could automate the whole process with a client program that polls for changes in the spot price for your instance size in your desired regions.**

This has the advantage that you could go one step further and use the same program to trigger instance shutdowns when the price rises and start another instance in a different region.

Amazon recently released a sample program to detect changes in spot prices by region and instance type: [How to Track Spot Instance Activity with the Spot-Notifications Sample Application](http://aws.amazon.com/code/7808666890647151).

Simply combine that with the [ec2 command-line tools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-StopInstances.html) to stop and start instances and you don't need to manually do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  I tried #1 and was able to setup the alert.  It looks as if the EstimatedCharges metric is the current cumulative billing charge for the instance.  For example right now it's $4.15.  So when I make an hourly alert at $4.25, in 2 hours the alert is triggered.  Doesn't seem to allow me to see the last 1 hour of charges, .05 cents.

Comment: I'm guessing #2 is what will have to be done.  Are you available to hire if so please contact me shane1800 at gmail